# JavaFX: GUI not refreshed

Tags: binding, javafx

I using the new released Java 8 version with JavaFX.

I wrote this little test program to simulate my problem.

```
public class Main extends Application{

    DoubleProperty widthProperty;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        HBox root = new HBox();
        HBox root2 = new HBox();
        HBox root3 = new HBox();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1200, 800);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        widthProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(400);

        root2.setPrefSize(400, 400);
        root3.setPrefHeight(400);
        root3.prefWidthProperty().bind(widthProperty);

        root2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");
        root3.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");

        root2.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                root2.setMinWidth(600);
            }
        });

        root2.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    widthProperty.set((Double) newValue); 
                }
            });

            //widthProperty.set((Double) newValue); 
        }
    });

    root.getChildren().addAll(root2, root3);
}
```

}

So what happens is, if i click on the root2, the width of it is changed. The changelistener recognize it and set the widthproperty to the width of root2. The widthproperty is binded to the root3 width. So now the root3 width should also be changed.

But the problem is, that i have to click twice on root2. Only after the second click, the GUI is updated. If i use Platform.runlater, the GUI is updated just in time after the first click.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the `minWidth` of the root2 on mouse click event, however you are setting your widthProperty variable on change of `widthProperty` of the root2. `minWidthProperty` and `widthProperty` are two different properties, but widthProperty is readonly property and cannot be set by the application. It will be controlled by the parent node at layout procedure (window resizing etc) with regarding min, max and preferred values of width. So instead add listener to minWidthProperty:

```
root2.minWidthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, final Number newValue) {
        widthProperty.set((Double) newValue);
    }
});
```

So why is it working with Platform.runLater?
Currently I cannot give you a concrete explanation since haven't observed deeper on JavaFX's system architecture. But the reason lays between FPS mechanism, application thread and renderers of JavaFX. Namely the value change event of your widthProperty may not be caught up in a same "clock cycle" of minWidthProperty.

Comment: i checked if the width of the root2 has changed, it does. then i checked if the width of the root3 also changed, and it does, so the width of bouth hbox is set correctly, but the ui is not refreshed.

Comment: yes, you are right, the widthproperty is readonly, but that doenst matter at this point. The minwidth is set from 400 to 600, so the width changed also. With listener on minwidth, it is the same result.

Comment: @AKR, In my test, adding a change listener to minWidthPrperty and widthProperty resulting differently. Maybe due to version, cause I have tested on JavaFX 2.2. Can you also?

Comment: im very confused right now... with java7 and javafx 2.2 it works, if i put the listener on the minwidth and bind the property to the minwidthproperty. in java8 also.